# Keep scrollbar visible on overflow-y: scroll for fixed height elements (Chrome 121)

Tags: css, google-chrome, sass, scroll, scrollbar

Following the recent updates on Chrome 121, I've been following https://syntackle.com/blog/changes-to-scrollbar-styling-in-chrome-121/ to make custom scrollbar styling work.

I've progressed with styling the scrollbar thumb and track (using `scrollbar-color` and `scrollbar-width`) however it seems that the scrollbar triggering has been recently updated to only show after hovering on the fixed height elements.

I need to be able to make the scrollbar visible by default for fixed height elements that have `overflow-y` set to `scroll` or `auto`, to indicate to users that the element is scrollable and contains more content within it.